# Setting H2 database name in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I have a Spring Boot project that uses H2. No matter what I set my database name to in my application.properties file, whey I bring up the H2 console, the name of the database is "test". I can log in and see my schema, but can't set the name of the database to anything but "test". No matter what name I use in the application.properties file, the name on the H2 console is "test".

My POM is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.repository</groupId>
<artifactId>repository</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>repository</name>
<description>repository project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

My application.properties file is

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

server.port=8081
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set "generate-unique-name" to false and set name as below:

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
spring.datasource.name=my-new-db-name
```

Answer (score 0):

The followingis the reference to database name - `file:~/test`. You need to change test to something else.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. No matter what I change that to, the URL in the H2 login console will come up as "jdbc:h2:~/test" and the database files will be name test.mv.db and test.trace.db. It seems to be ignoring the value set in application.properties.

Comment: H2 console it is just the helper app you can connect to any h2 file base db. Basically don't hesitate to change the url value in console. Application properties and h2 console doesn't conneted at all so you need to change url manually

Answer (score 0):

- I've tried the following settings and it worked as expected: rcp_h2.mv.db file was created.
- For H2 URL: As Anton suggested - just go ahead and replace the default URL with your i.e. "jdbc:h2:mem:rcp_h2", it will get remembered so next time you don't need to do it.

If still the problem persists, you should try change other settings for example: port # or "spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console" -> "spring.h2.console.path=/h2" to see if it takes effect after the app restart. If not then probably something is wrong with your project setup.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:c:/temp/rcp_h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

server.port=8081
```